# Setting a form as an MDI child of a main form?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mdi, mdiparent

I have a main form application which is an MDI container. A user can press a button to make a new form pop up (not as an MDI child), and then from this new form that popped up, I want to be able to have a button that creates a different form as an MDI child.

In the main form I have:

```
ResSelectForm resSelectForm = new ResSelectForm();
resSelectForm.Show();
```

So in the `resSelect` form that popped up, when the user presses an OK button, I have:

```
ImageForm imageForm = new ImageForm();
imageForm.MdiParent = Mainform; // doesn't work
imageForm.Show();
```

I get the following error:

> Error CS0119 'MainForm' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: What errors do you get? Are they compile time errors or runtime errors?

Comment: Error CS0119 'MainForm' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is you were trying to access the `Mainform` type and not an instance of it. To fix the problem you would have to pass the instance to the `ResSelectForm` constructor like so:

```
ResSelectForm resSelectForm = new ResSelectForm(this);
```

Then in the `ResSelectForm` constructor do this:

```
private Mainform _mainform; //Variable to use throughout the class

public ResSelectForm(Mainform mainform)
{
    _mainform = mainform;
}
```

Lastly whenever you need to access `Mainform` you'd access the variable, in your case like so:

```
imageForm.MdiParent = _mainform;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using a dialog box for it, since it's essentially the same thing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aDsXyiBLsI

Comment: Please summarize the solution in your answer so that future users can benefit from your findings.